How to collect the stack for the spark driver and executor before the task quit?
Currently, my Spark application stops due task timing out. It does not output any useful log before it quits.
I want to collect the stack info to check whether there is deadlock or other reason.

Spark REST API provides endpoint to retrieve thread dump for any running executor /applications/[app-id]/executors/[executor-id]/threads. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

@mazaneicha
this is the stack info of the executors. How to collect the driver stack info.

In client mode you can use Java jstack -l <pid> to get thread dump of a driver process . In cluster mode, executor-0 is the driver.
